# How do I copy and paste row in jqgrid

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I want to use copy and paste in jqgrid.
But jqgrid doesn't see that function.
My grid has a row add button, so if you press the button, you can edit it.
In this state, I want to copy another row and paste it into a new row.

[image: 1]

Example link
https://paramquery.com/pro/demos/copy_paste

Like this ....

I would appreciate some help getting this resolved

Answer (score 0):

To copy row to new row you from the same grid you can:

1. get the data from a row with rowId using getRowData method. This will return a object with data.
2. Add new row with the same data using addRowData
3. use editRow to edit the new added row.

More more information on the methods consult the [docs](http://www.guriddo.net/documentation/guriddo/javascript/user-guide/basic-grid/#methods).